# why does kmean color segmentation show different color every time?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors, image-segmentation

i am learning how to segment colors by using kmean clustering just like the example in matlab 2015a. But each time i run the codes, the colors that i want are in different clusters. For example, for the first run,it will display that yellow is in cluster 1 and blue is in cluster 2. When i run it again, they will switch to different cluster. How to make the yellow and blue is in specific clusters even if i run it again and again? Please help me. Thanks in advance

This is the code that i use:

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg','Select the MATLAB code file');

he1= imread(FileName);
cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab_he = applycform(he1,cform);
figure (2)
imshow (lab_he)


ab = double(lab_he(:,:,2:3));
nrows = size(ab,1);
ncols = size(ab,2);
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);

nColors = 3;
% repeat the clustering 3 times to avoid local minima
[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean',           ...
                                  'Replicates',3);



pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
figure (3)
imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');

segmented_images = cell(1,3);
rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels,[1 1 3]);

for k = 1:nColors
    color = he1;
    color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
    segmented_images{k} = color;
end
%%
figure (4)
imshow(segmented_images{1}), title('objects in cluster 1');

%% 
figure (5)
imshow(segmented_images{2}), title('objects in cluster 2');

%%
figure (6)
imshow(segmented_images{3}), title('objects in cluster 3');
%%
a = im2bw (segmented_images{2},0.05);
figure (7)
imshow (a);

b = im2bw (segmented_images{3},0.05);
figure (8)
imshow (b);
```

In my situation, the region with yellow color should be in cluster 2 and the area with blue region should be in cluster 3. Please show me how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first output of `kmeans` is in the *index* of the cluster and not a color. The color that you are referring to is the one that is displayed by MATLAB when you visualize it.

With kmeans, the initial cluster centers are chosen randomly from the input data. Because of this the *order is random*. As such, which cluster index gets assigned to a pixel will be different each time you call the algorithm but the pixels within a cluster should be placed within the same cluster and have the same cluster index *as each other* with successive calls.

If you want the actual color corresponding to each cluster, you will want to use the [second output](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html?refresh=true#outputarg_C) of `kmeans` (the cluster centroids) to map the cluster index to a color. You can easily do this using `ind2rgb`.

```
pixel_labels = ind2rgb(cluster_idx, cluster_center);
imshow(pixel_labels)
```

If you simply want the cluster index values to remain the same after successive calls, you can use the `cluster_center` to ensure a consistent index assignment

```
[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab, nColors);
[~, ind] = sortrows(cluster_center);

pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx, nrows, ncols);

for k = 1:numel(ind)
    pixel_labels(cluster_idx == k) = ind(k);
end
```

This can be modified if you want a specific color to be in a specific cluster.

```
%// Define yellow
yellow = [1 1 0];

%// Define blue
blue = [0 0 1];

%// Find the centroid closest to yellow
[~, yellowind] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, cluster_center, yellow).^2, 2));

%// Find the one closest to blue
[~, blueind] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, cluster_center, blue).^2, 2));

%// Now assign them to clusters with yellow as 2 and blue as 3
segmented_images{1} = cluster_idx == setdiff(1:3, [yellowind, blueind]);
segmented_images{2} = cluster_idx == yellowind;
segmented_images{3} = cluster_idx == blueind;
```

Comment: im sorry sir, could you explain to me how this works?

Comment: @badrulhisham I have updated the answer in hopes of making it clearer

Comment: thank you very much for your help sir, i will try to implement these into my coding

Comment: im sorry for disturbing you sir, but what does this error means?                         b = zeros(size(a)); b(:) = cm(a,3);

Comment: @badrulhisham It doesn't look like you posted in the error

Comment: undefined function ID?                                                                         [cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab, nColors);
[~, ind] = sortrows(cluster_center);

pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx, nrows, ncols);

for k = 1:numel(ind)
    pixel_labels(ID == k) = ind(k);
end

Comment: @badrulhisham That's just the code I poasted. I do not see an error.

Comment: im apologize for my shallowness because im still new to matlab. From the codes that you posted, how should i implement them?

Comment: @badrulhisham You should be able to copy/paste them. They use the variable names that you already have so it should just work.

Comment: but for for k = 1:numel(ind)
    pixel_labels(ID == k) = ind(k);
end the ID is undefined function

Comment: @badrulhisham Sorry that was a typo. It should have been `cluster_idx` instead of `ID`

Comment: im using matlab 2015a, is there any compatible issues with the coding above? cause i cant seem to be using these codes

Comment: @badrulhisham Which ones are you trying to use and what error are you getting?

Comment: what does it mean by this? Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match
each other.